# In python client library for BigQuery Storage API what do bigquery_storage_v1beta1* modules contain?

Tags: google-bigquery

Python client library for Google BigQuery Storage API has several modules:

- bigquery_storage_v1
- bigquery_storage_v1beta1
- bigquery_storage_v1beta2

Do *beta* modules have outdated stuff that shouldn't be used anymore? Or it contains functionality that once ready will be moved to `bigquery_storage_v1`?

Comment: Have you read about Google API [versioning](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/versioning) strategy in GCP documentation pages, that might shed light on the versioning schemas in detail?

Answer (score 1):

Answer from Google API [versioning](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/versioning) documentation:

> An individual release is an alpha or beta release that is expected to
>   be available for a limited time period before its functionality is
>   incorporated into the stable channel, after which the individual
>   release will be shut down.